# javascript hide and display div elements selecting multiple elements

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a website dashboard using html,css and javascript. In the dashboard selection menu I added few options for user to select the data want to display on the rightside webpage. For the each selection option I add a click EventListner function using forEach loop. When the user click a option I get the Id of that element and matched it with the data table id want to display. Then the adding classname .active{display: block;} to the selected element display the user selected table.

```
   When firsttime user select elemen javascript eventListner Functio wokrs, But when user select the same element for the second time ` document.getElementById(elementId)` return null and whole program crashes. 

 <div class="dashboard">
<div class="menu">
  <div class="menu-btns">
    <a id="dashboard" class="menu-btn">Dashboard</a>
    <a id="posted" class="menu-btn">Posted Jobs</a>
    <a id="applicants" class="menu-btn">Applicants</a>
    <a id="newJob" class="menu-btn">New Job</a>
    <a id="myProfile" class="menu-btn">My Profile</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="interface">

  <div id="main-dashboard" class=""></div>

  <div id="publihed-posts" class="published">
    <table class="published-job-post-table active">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Id</th>
          <th>Title</th>
          <th>Published Date</th>
          <th>Closing Date</th>
          <th>Edit</th>
          <th>Delete</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Senior Software Engineer</td>
          <td>01/02/2022</td>
          <td>01/02/2022</td>
          <td><button class="btn btn-db-edit">Edit</button></td>
          <td><button class="btn btn-db-delete">Delete</button></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div id="recieved-applicants" class="applicants">
    <table class="recieved-application-table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Id</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Title</th>
          <th>Applied Date</th>
          <th>Check</th>
          <th>Delete</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div id="vacancy-published" class="vacancy-publish">

    <p class="vacancy-form-heading">Vacancy Publish Form</p>

    <form class="vacany-publish-form" action="">
          <div>Form Content<div/>
  </form>
</div>
```

```
let dashboardBtnEl = document.querySelectorAll(".menu-btn");
let elementId;

dashboardBtnEl.forEach((btn) => {
  btn.addEventListener("click", (event) => {

let selectedEl = event.target.id;
if (elementId) document.getElementById(elementId).remove("active");

switch (selectedEl) {
  case "dashboard":
    elementId = "main-dashboard";
    break;
  case "posted":
    elementId = "publihed-posts";
    break;
  case "applicants":
    elementId = "recieved-applicants";
    break;
  case "newJob":
    elementId = "vacancy-published";
    break;
  case "myProfile":
    elementId = "edit-profile";
    break;
}

console.log(elementId);
console.log(document.getElementById(elementId);
document.getElementById(elementId).classList.add("active");
```

});
});

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here

`document.getElementById(elementId).remove("active");`

change it with

`document.getElementById(elementId).classList.remove("active");`

You are removing the matched element from the DOM

Comment: yes that was the error I missed the classList. Thank you..